# Doctrine where in with Doctrine_Query

Tags: doctrine, dql

is it possible to make :

```
$q->createQuery('q')
  ->whereIn('q.id', $q2)
```

Where $q2 is an other Doctrine_Query object. Because my subquery is complex and I don't want to write it in SQL...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, according to the [Doctrine API documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/1.2/doctrine/doctrine_query_abstract.html#whereIn%28%29), you can't pass another query object to `whereIn()`, so you will have to fetch your ID-s beforehand and pass them in an array. Be careful though, because if you pass an empty array, then there will be **NO FILTERING** for those ID-s. In other words: it will return all rows present in your table, instead of none.

Comment: Not very intuitive, is this fixed in doctrine 2, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

While using whereIn the parameter should be an array. You can use execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY) to return an array instead of an object.