# How to return an empty Doctrine_Collection?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, dql, doctrine-collection

I've a method that returns a Doctrine_Collection, with a `whereIn()` clause :

```
public function getByValues($values)
{
  if (!is_array($values))
    throw new sfException('Wrong parameter type. Excepted array.');

  return Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('Anomaly a')
    ->whereIn('a.value', $values);
}
```

However, when `$values` is an empty array, this method return **all the rows that are in the AnomalyTable**. This isn't an unexpected behavior, as documented in Doctrine documentation, and written here : [Doctrine where in with Doctrine_Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433151/doctrine-where-in-with-doctrine-query/5434628#5434628)

However, I would like to return an empty `Doctrine_Collection` instead of the result of my query, when `$values` is an empty array.

Any ideas on how I can do that ?

Thanks =)

### Edit:

Adding an impossible clause, like `->where('1=0')` would do the trick, but it is an unnecessary request to the DB server. Does anyone have a better idea ?

Comment: Why you still want to query DB when you already know that you'll only get nothing? Just check $values, and if it's empty - don't query at all.

Comment: I don't want to query if `$values` is empty, just return an empty `Doctrine_Collection`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And what about (you need also the execute method to get the result of the query ! with that the return type will be the same everytime) :

```
public function getByValues($values)
{
  if (!is_array($values))
    throw new sfException('Wrong parameter type. Excepted array.');

  if (empty($values)) {
    return new Doctrine_Collection('Anomaly');
  }

  return Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('Anomaly a')
    ->whereIn('a.value', $values)
    ->execute()
  ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By value, I assume you mean `$values` right? just add something to check if values is empty and then manually supply an empty collection.

```
if(empty($values)) 
   return Doctine_Query::create()->from('Anomaly a')->where('1=0');
```

Comment: Maybe because this way you load up your DB server with queries that do nothing?

Comment: & @nicola : that is a clever way, I think of, but as Wallgate suggest, it would be an unnecessary query to the DB server.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(count($values)){
  return Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('Anomaly a')
    ->whereIn('a.value', $values);
} else {
  return Doctine_Query::create()
    ->from('Anomaly a')
    ->where('0=1');
}
```

Comment: `$values.length`? values is an array not an object. Also you are missing a semi colon mr moon :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's impossible to do that.
The Doctrine_Collection is more than a resultset/array of objects. It also has means of deleting and adding objects and keeping that state.

That's probably also why many native Doctrine functions return `FALSE` when no results were found. (For instance, the NestedSet functions).

So, for you it's probably best to return FALSE as well. or maybe an empty array. Both arrays as Doctrine_Collection can be used in a `foreach` loop and `count` function.
Should you want to use the `delete` and `add` functions, you could just call the constructor.

Comment: Ty for the precisions on the role of `Doctrine_Collection`.

Answer (score 1):

I personnaly use the following trick:

```
public function getByValues($values)
{
  if (!is_array($values))
    throw new sfException('Wrong parameter type. Excepted array.');

  $values = empty($values) ? array(-1) : $values;

  return Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('Anomaly a')
    ->whereIn('a.value', $values);
}
```

Works great even if somewhat hackish.

Comment: Works good as long as `-1` is an impossible value. I guess I'll stick with that.

Comment: I put -1 because WHERE IN clauses are often used on primary keys, but you can set "ChuckNorr1z" as the impossible value if you don't fear it enough ;)

Comment: That way you'll still have a (unnecessary) round trip to to the database.